# Is it possible to run QuestDB on NFS?

Tags: questdb

I'm curious if it's possible to run QuestDB on any kind of distributed or networked file system. Are there any limitations or considerations for using this as the main storage for a QuestDB instance? Are there any guidelines or recommendations for other database systems that can be applied to this use case?

Comment: What did you find when you visited their website or GitHub repository?

Answer (score 0):

We can't use NFS or a similar networked filesystem directly with QuestDB, but we may copy a backup to such a filesystem after a backup has been made.
see
https://questdb.io/docs/operations/backup/